# How to build query params with array []

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router-dom

i am preparing a query params for an array, but now i would like to have with this format

```
?vegetable[]=tomato&foo[]=lechuce
```

this is my current code:

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams()
searchParams.set('vegetable', ['tomato', 'lechuce'])
```

with that i am getting

```
?vegetable=tomato%2Clechuce
```

but i need

```
?vegetable[]=tomato&foo[]=lechuce
```

**and my other small question is:**

how can i add '?' to start to search

i am doing like this:

navigate(location?.pathname + '?' + searchParams.toString())

its necesary use `navigate`?

Comment: what does your title have to do with this?

Comment: @DanielA.White sorry i keept my previous question, and i forgot change the title

Comment: I'm guessing react-router doesn't support that - you might want to consult their documentation

Comment: `useSearchParams` returns a `URLSearchParams` object

Comment: @Konrad that is using URLSearchParams and i am using react-route

Comment: It's the same object, but wrapped. You can also use the setter `setSearchParams({ vegetables:  ['tomato', 'lechuce'] })`

Comment: @Konrad how can i put '?' to start to search?, in the below of my question i added a small question more please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800658/react-router-v6-navigate-to-a-url-with-searchparams

Comment: @Konrad with your answer i am getting like this ?vegetable=tomato&vegetable=lechuce&foo=other but i need with [] example: ?vegetable[]=tomato&foo[]=lechuce

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62246426/5089567

Comment: `"?vegetable[]=tomato&foo[]=lechuce"` doesn't exactly make sense. What is the point of appending a `"[]"` to each query parameter? How does the array `['tomato', 'lechuce']` get converted/split to `"vegetable"` ***and*** `"foo"` parameters? `searchParams.set('vegetable', ['tomato', 'lechuce'])` is how'd I'd recommend you pass an array in the queryString. What exactly is the issue or problem with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion. How about to use `set` and `append` function like this.

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

searchParams.set('vegetable', 'vege1');
searchParams.set('foo', 'foo1');

searchParams.append('vegetable', 'vege2');
searchParams.append('foo', 'foo2');
```

You can check this value :

```
console.log(earchParams.toString());
```

Let me know if you still have more issues.